# How does the attack dog killstreak work?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

How many dogs spawn with the attack dog killstreak? Is there a set amount, or do they just spawn for X seconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dogs spawn for ~60 seconds continuously.  There tends to only be 4-5 dogs active at once, but when one dies another replaces it by jumping into the map somewhere else.

However, the dog mechanic is quite a bit different in Black-ops then it was in World at War.  Because dogs are harder to get (11 kill streak instead of 7) they now kill in 1 bite.  But instead of immediately 'knowing' the location of enemies dogs are now attracted to gunfire, making them much easier to avoid

Comment: I never realized they spawned for so long. I gues that's why they're so hard to get.

Comment: Yeah the 1 bite/kill makes them pretty damn scary as well.. Its like a chopper gunner that you can't shoot down!  But as I mentioned above, you can actually hide from them in this game

Comment: Dogs bark so loud it's almost hard to miss them, and they also go down in one bullet, they themselves are never a threat factor for me. Though in the RIGHT hands, they are excellent distraction and while you are looking out frantically around, some guy stabs you in the face.

Answer (score 3):

The attack dogs will continuously spawn for about 60 seconds.